# How can a hash function return different values for the same input?

Tags: python, hash-function

```
def hashValue(a: List[int]) -> int:
    h = len(a)
    for val in a:
        h = h * 314159 + val
    return h 

length = len(grid[0])
for i in range(length):
    h = hashValue(grid[i])
    print(h)

for j in range(0,length):
    col = np.empty(length, dtype=int)
    for i in range(length):
        col[i] = grid[i][j]
    h = hashValue(col)
    print(h)
```

For this grid:

```
[[3, 1, 2, 2], [1, 4, 4, 5], [2, 4, 2, 2], [2, 4, 2, 2]]
```

Hashes for grid rows:

```
38963597787757876482482
38963535775657743299288
38963566781855853392646
38963566781855853392646
```

Hashes for grid cols:

```
4074304083303469490
4012291983170286295
4043298181280379654
4043298279976256935
```

But `[3, 1, 2, 2]` col index 0 is same as row index 0, so I would expect the same hash.

And `[2, 4, 2, 2]` col index 2 is same as row index 2, 3, so I would expect the same hash.

Comment: Please show a **complete** example, including the main-level code that calls the function.

Comment: I suspect this is due to mixing native python datatypes and numpy datatypes.  If I replace `col = np.empty(length, dtype=int)` with `col = [0] * length`, I get identical results for the first row and col.

Comment: I get a `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar multiply` in the column section. On the rows, I presume you're operating directly on raw python ints (as opposed to numpy ints in the colum logic) which accounts for the difference. try changing your column logic to `for col in zip(*grid): print(hashValue(col))` and you'll get the expected results

Comment: Ok I didn't know numpy datatypes are different than native datatypes. Why is that ?

Comment: python ints have arbitrary precision. numpy ints have fixed precision

Comment: Python integers can be arbitrarily large (well, not really, they are restricted by available memory) while numpy integers have a finite range of possible values.